# Python - ATBS Appendix B - Can't find '__main__' module in C:\\ path error

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to complete Appendix B in Automate the Boring Stuff - 'Running Python Programs on Windows' however when I WIN-R the script and argv, I get the error "can't find '__ main __' module in C:\ path.

I have created the .py script as well as the batch file, changed the system variable path but still can't get the program to run from WIN-R.

My script for pw.py is as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# pw.py - An insecure password locker program.

PASSWORDS = {'email': 'F7min1BDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6',
                'blog': 'VmALvQyKAxiVH5G8v01if1MLZF3sdt',
                'luggage': '12345'}

import sys
import pyperclip

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1]   #first command line arg is the account name

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print('Password for ' + account + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no account named ' + account)
```

My pw.bat file is as follows:

```
@py.exe C:\Users\lukev\PythonScripts %*
@pause
```

When I run `pw email` in WIN-R, I get the following error:
`C:\Users\lukev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Users\\lukev\\PythonScripts'`

From my research I found out the shebang line shouldn't be as described in the book and should instead be `#! /usr/bin/env python3` and another possibility be if I had multiple versions of Python installed however I don't have other versions installed and still have the issue.

Below are screenshots of the python file, the batch file, system environment variables, and error message:

[pw.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwdyk.png)

[pw.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeh8b.png)

[System variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK6Em.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlIG5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use

> ```
> @py.exe C:\Users\lukev\PythonScripts %*
> ```

in the batch-file. The path being passed to `py.exe` is a folder path.

This creates an error:

> ```
> C:\Users\lukev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Users\\lukev\\PythonScripts'
> ```

The error is precise. The path is a folder path, so what Python does is look for an entry point. As displayed, that entry point is `__main__.py`. If it cannot find the entry point, it displays the error message.

If you want to execute a file, then execute it direct:

```
@py.exe C:\Users\lukev\PythonScripts\pw.py %*
```

To understand the `__main__` module entry point, create a folder named `C:\PythonExecutable` and create a file inside the directory named `__main__.py`. Insert into this file the following code:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Check command line arguments.
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        if sys.argv[1] == '-h':
            print('I am here to help')
        else:
            for index, item in enumerate(sys.argv):
                print(index, item)
    else:
        print('I am ', __name__)
```

Enter some commands in a Command Prompt:

> ```
> C:\> py PythonExecutable
> I am  __main__
>
> C:\> py PythonExecutable -h
> I am here to help
>
> C:\> py PythonExecutable arg1 arg2 arg3 "I am the fourth"
> 0 PythonExecutable
> 1 arg1
> 2 arg2
> 3 arg3
> 4 I am the fourth
>
> C:\>
> ```

A shebang line in `__main__.py` is not applied as `py.exe` does not read from this file.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, that was a very thorough explanation